# What host and port to use for http plugin for a Logstash container running in K8s pod?

Tags: python, kubernetes, python-requests, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am receiving this error `Error: Cannot assign requested address` in logstash when attempting to set up a pipeline that uses http input plugin.

I am trying to send data from a Python process to logstash using the Python requests http library. I am not sure which host and port to use in my logstash http input configs. Should I be using the defaults, the logstash pod ClusterIP service IP, the logstash pod IP, or something else?

```
input {
    http {
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        port => 80
    }
  }
```

The defaults url is 0.0.0.0:80 but I get a connection error on the Python side. I've also tried the url of the Logstash K8s pod that the logstash container is running in and get `Error: Cannot assign requested address` in the logstash container.

Edit: included logstash service details

```
Name:              central-logstash
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=logstash
                   chart=logstash-1.10.0
                   heritage=Tiller
                   release=central-logstash
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=logstash,release=central-logstash
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.110.133.189
Port:              beats  5044/TCP
TargetPort:        beats/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.0.79:5044
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Can you share more info about how you are deploing logstash in k8s? are you using a service?

Comment: yes. i have added service details

Comment: I think that the ports in the 1-1024 range are restricted to root. Since I don't think your logstash service is running as root, that would explain the `Cannot assign requested address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching to TCP to avoid HTTP headers in my messages.

In my Logstash Helm configuration (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/logstash), I set up the service as such:

```
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  annotations: {}
  ports:
     tcp-data:
       port: 1514
       targetPort: tcp-data
       protocol: TCP
     tcp-event:
       port: 1515
       targetPort: tcp-event
       protocol: TCP

ports:
  - name: tcp-data
    containerPort: 1514
    protocol: TCP
  - name: tcp-event
    containerPort: 1515
    protocol: TCP
```

And the tcp plugin:

```
inputs:
 data: |-
    input {
        tcp {
            port => 1514
            type => json
        }
      }
 event: |-
    input {
        tcp {
            port => 1515
            type => json
        }
      }
```

And then on the Python side, I was able to use the socket library to send messages to Logstash using the Logstash clusterIP service's IP and port 1514 or 1515.

Answer (score 0):

As per your information, you are using helm to deploy and the version of the docker image from elastic on the stable chart is the `7.1.1`

If you check the Dockerfile for [that](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/7.1/Dockerfile) version

They create a user logstash [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/7.1/Dockerfile#L10)

And during the Dockerfile definition switch to root but returns at the end to that user, because of that you cannot use port `80`

Try to use a different port like `8080` and adjust all other services that need to connect to logstash to use the new port or map that port on the service to use on the services level the `80` port but with the target pointing to the `8080`